# Is $x\mapsto \sqrt{xx^*}$ a norm?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A real $*$-algebra $X$ (real algebra with linear operation $*$ such that $(xy)^* = y^*x^*$ and $x^{**} = x$ for all $x,y\in X$) is said to be nicely normed if $X$ is unital and the operation $*$ has the following additional properties:
$$xx^* = x^*x \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad x+x^* \in \mathbb{R}$$
for all $x\in X$ with $xx^* = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$.
Define $||x|| = \sqrt{xx^*}$. I cannot prove that this is a norm; my problem is only the triangular inequality. I have tried with $\text{Re} (x) = (x+x^*)/2$ and $\text{Im} (x) = (x-x^*)/2$ (it can be seen that $||x||^2 = \text{Re}^2(x)- \text{Im}^2(x)$)
and with the direct approach, but I did not succeed.

Comment: Is $*$ linear? I mean, $(x+y)^* = x^* + y^*$?

Comment: You surely want to allow $xx^* = x^*x \geq 0$ as well ;-) Also, this looks a lot like Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @dust05 Yes, it is (written).

Comment: @AlexR Yeah, it does. But noone says that $X$ is commutative and thats my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can first apply a positive linear functional to both sides and check that, and then use some version of Hahn-Banach to say that $\varphi(z) \geq 0$ for all positive linear $\varphi$ implies that $z\geq 0$? Not sure about this though.

Comment: I think you also want $1^\ast = 1$, no? (Or is this a consequence of other axioms?)

Comment: @user43208 It is a consequence:), since $1 = (1^*)^* = (1\cdot 1^*)^* = (1^*)^*\cdot 1^* = 1^*$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I do not know anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comments to my earlier reply (which was not satisfactory for the OP's purposes), I emailed John Baez to ask for a proof. He very kindly responded as follows (paraphrasing ever so slightly):

"The definition of 'nicely normed' includes the fact that $aa^* > 0$ for any nonzero $a$.  This means $aa^*$ can be identified with a positive real number.  Doing this, it follows that the mapping $a\mapsto aa^*$ is a positive definite quadratic form.  It follows that the square root of this obeys the triangle inequality.   (Up to an invertible linear transformation, any positive definite quadratic form on a finite-dimensional vector space is the square of the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.)"

(Many thanks to John for this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof. First, we have $\|tx\| = |t|\cdot\|x\|$ for scalars $t$ (easy).

In this case, the triangle inequality is equivalent to the fact that the unit ball $\{v \in X: \|v\| \leq 1\}$ is convex, viz., if $\|v\|, \|w\| \leq 1$, then $\|tv + (1-t)w\| \leq 1$ when $0 \leq t \leq 1$. In one direction, to prove that the inequality $\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$ follows from convexity, suppose without loss of generality that $x, y \neq 0$, and put $v = x/\|x\|$, $w = y/\|y\|$, and $t = \|x\|/(\|x\|+\|y\|)$, observing that $(x+y)/(\|x\|+\|y\|) = tv+(1-t)w$ has norm less than $1$ by convexity.

To prove the unit ball is convex, start from $\|x\|^2 = \text{Re}(x)^2 - \text{Im}(x)^2$, borrowing notation from the OP. Note that

- $(2\text{Im}(x))^2 = (x-x^\ast)^2 \leq 0$. Proof: if $y = x-x^\ast$, then $y^\ast = -y$, so $-y^2 = y^\ast y \geq 0$.

It follows that the real scalar $\text{Re}(x)$ satisfies $|\text{Re}(x)| \leq \|x\|$.

Next, we have $\|x y\|^2 = x y y^\ast x^\ast = (y y^\ast)(x x^\ast)$ (since $y y^\ast$ is a real scalar, it commutes with any $x$), so $\|xy\| = \|x\|\cdot \|y\|$.

Putting all this together, we show convexity of the unit ball. Suppose $x, y$ have norm $1$. Then for $t \in [0, 1]$, we have

$$\|tx + (1-t)y\|^2 = (tx + (1-t)y)(tx^\ast + (1-t)y^\ast) = t^2\|x\|^2 + t(1-t)(x y^\ast + y x^\ast) + (1-t)^2\|y\|^2 \qquad (1)$$

where $x y^\ast + y x^\ast = 2\text{Re}(x y^\ast) \leq 2\|x y^\ast\| = 2\|x\|\cdot \|y\| = 2$. Applying this inequality to equation (1), we get

$$\|tx + (1-t)y\|^2 \leq t^2 + 2t(1-t) + (1-t)^2 = 1$$

which completes the proof.

Comment: Very clever idea. May I ask what is motivation for it? But, there remains just one problem: octonions are $*$-algebra and they are not associative. They have multiplicative norm anyway. Unfortunately, I cannot modify your proof, because you use it when you prove $||xy||=||x||\cdot ||y||$.

Comment: @Joel Oh! I had assumed "algebra" meant associative algebra (as it indeed does in many contexts) -- perhaps you should mention this explicitly in your question. I'm not sure how to answer the "motivation question", but you can look here for some musings of mine on this convexity business: ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/p-norms May I ask where this problem comes from?

Comment: If you are willing to assume the algebra is alternative, the proof I gave can be modified. Or, if you are assuming algebras are finite-dimensional, one can haul out some big guns (Atiyah-Adams) to the effect that division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic to the reals, complexes, quaternions, or octonions. See also here: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node5.html

Comment: Your source (Baez) is one of my problems. Everywhere on the internet is just simply said: Let be $A$ nicely normed ... and we can define norm $||x|| = xx^*$ (and nothing is said about associativity, alternation etc.), but I didn't find any proofs ... To say more,  your source is sometimes mentioned as theirs:) You gave quite well on my 'motivation question', though.